# Magento Store I started working with has a custom cart and I'm getting this error SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: mysql, magento

I started working with a store who has had their checkout process customized by someone other than myself.  I've added some custom product options to a product to test a new marketing method and everything adds to the cart just fine, sends the right price to the first page of the checkout process but when I click to go to the page that you would enter shipping info etc. on I receive this message.

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Trace:

```
#0 /chroot/home/collinsb/collinsbridge.com/html/dev/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /chroot/home/collinsb/collinsbridge.com/html/dev/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /chroot/home/collinsb/collinsbridge.com/html/dev/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /chroot/home/collinsb/collinsbridge.com/html/dev/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT * FROM c...', Array)
#4 /chroot/home/collinsb/collinsbridge.com/html/dev/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(389): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT * FROM c...', Array)
#5 /chroot/home/collinsb/collinsbridge.com/html/dev/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(753): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT * FROM c...', Array)
#6 /chroot/home/collinsb/collinsbridge.com/html/dev/app/design/frontend/default/collings-bridge/template/checkout/onepage/progress.phtml(164): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchRow('SELECT * FROM c...')
#7 /chroot/home/collinsb/collinsbridge.com/html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/chroot/home/co...')
#8 /chroot/home/collinsb/collinsbridge.com/html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#9 /chroot/home/collinsb/collinsbridge.com/html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#10 /chroot/home/collinsb/collinsbridge.com/html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(803): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#11 /chroot/home/collinsb/collinsbridge.com/html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(570): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#12 /chroot/home/collinsb/collinsbridge.com/html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(510): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('checkout.progre...', true)
#13 /chroot/home/collinsb/collinsbridge.com/html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Wrapper.php(52): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('', true, true)
#14 /chroot/home/collinsb/collinsbridge.com/html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(803): Mage_Page_Block_Html_Wrapper->_toHtml()
#15 /chroot/home/collinsb/collinsbridge.com/html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#16 /chroot/home/collinsb/collinsbridge.com/html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(803): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#17 /chroot/home/collinsb/collinsbridge.com/html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(570): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#18 /chroot/home/collinsb/collinsbridge.com/html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(514): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('right', true)
#19 /chroot/home/collinsb/collinsbridge.com/html/dev/app/design/frontend/default/collings-bridge/template/page/2columns-right.phtml(52): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('right')
#20 /chroot/home/collinsb/collinsbridge.com/html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/chroot/home/co...')
#21 /chroot/home/collinsb/collinsbridge.com/html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#22 /chroot/home/collinsb/collinsbridge.com/html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#23 /chroot/home/collinsb/collinsbridge.com/html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(803): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#24 /chroot/home/collinsb/collinsbridge.com/html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(529): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#25 /chroot/home/collinsb/collinsbridge.com/html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(391): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#26 /chroot/home/collinsb/collinsbridge.com/html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(508): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#27 /chroot/home/collinsb/collinsbridge.com/html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->indexAction()
#28 /chroot/home/collinsb/collinsbridge.com/html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(253): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#29 /chroot/home/collinsb/collinsbridge.com/html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#30 /chroot/home/collinsb/collinsbridge.com/html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(347): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#31 /chroot/home/collinsb/collinsbridge.com/html/dev/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#32 /chroot/home/collinsb/collinsbridge.com/html/dev/index.php(82): Mage::run('', 'store')
#33 {main}
```

I'm sure the answer is staring me in the face somewhere in there but I can't seem to figure it out.  Any insight at all would be appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT:  This is the block of code in progress.phtml that seems to be creating the problem... any thoughts?

```
$ProUrl = $_newProduct->getProductUrl()."?".$simp_pro_id."~".$splited_val;
                                                      $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
                                                      $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
                                                      $tableName = $resource->getTableName('frame_lens_combine_image');
                                                      $query = 'SELECT * FROM '.$tableName.' WHERE product_id='.$_newProduct->getId().' AND frame_product_id='.$simp_pro_id.' AND lens_option_id='.$len_id.''; 
                                                      $img_arr='';
                                                      $img_arr = $readConnection->fetchRow($query);
                                                      $img222='';
                                                     // $img222 = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)."frame_lens/".$img_arr['image_name'];
                                                      $folderURL = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)."frame_lens/";
                                                      $imageURL = $folderURL . $img_arr['image_name'];
                                                      $basePath = Mage::getBaseDir(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . DS . "frame_lens" . DS . $img_arr['image_name'];
                                                      $newPath = Mage::getBaseDir(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . DS . "resized" . DS . $img_arr['image_name'];
                                                      $imageObj = new Varien_Image($basePath);
                                                      $imageObj->constrainOnly(TRUE);
                                                      $imageObj->keepAspectRatio(TRUE);
                                                      $imageObj->keepFrame(FALSE);
                                                      //$width, $height - sizes you need (Note: when keepAspectRatio(TRUE), height would be ignored)
                                                      $imageObj->resize('118');
                                                      //$newPath - name of resized image
                                                      $imageObj->save($newPath);
                                                      $resizedURL = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . "resized" . DS . $img_arr['image_name'];
                                                      $img222=$resizedURL;
```

Comment: There simply isn't enough data in the trace to work with.  I can tell by looking at it that your custom theme is using direct SQL calls in the `.phtml` files, which is generally bad practice.  Start by looking in the `/app/design/frontend/default/collings-bridge/template/checkout/onepage/progress.phtml` file on line `164` and seeing if commenting out the SQL call stops the error from occurring.

Comment: Hi Axel thanks for your reply - that did stop the first error from occurring but now it's giving me this "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1065 Query was empty". The products that do not have custom options attached still work during checkout jsut fine, only the products with custom options break. I didnt actually build this and know it's terrible practice, but it's what I have to work with and I'm totally lost.  What file would you need to see to get a better idea?

Comment: I also added the entire block into the original post if you need to see that

Comment: This really isn't a question that can be answered on this site.  Without knowing the extent of the hacks, there really is no solid answer I can provide.  I would recommend trying to debug it further yourself, or hiring an experienced Magento developer to reintroduce the customization you require correctly.  Hacked up template files and custom code is nearly impossible to debug without access to the actual Magento installation.  If it's something affecting the performance of your site, you can try switching to the default Magento theme and working backwards from there.